# Is a lock obtained with "select for update" released when the stored procedure ends, even when nested in another SP?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hana

I am on SAP HANA DB SP8. How are locks handled when nesting stored procedures?

More specifically: I have one SP called `p_outer` which calls another SP called `p_inner`. `p_inner` locks one row of table `T` via `select ... for update`. After `p_inner` returns to `p_outer`, will the row in `T` still be locked? There is no explicit commit statement in `p_inner`. The server's autocommit setting is probably set to false, but does this matter?

I did not find this specific issue documented, neither did I find previous material on this specifically for SAP HANA. Other DBMs may handle it differently.

Comment: Were you able to test this with your setup?

Comment: @stb No, unfortunately not. I'm thinking whether the setup would be more tedious than trying to find the source code or code author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered the question in your cross post here: http://www.saphana.com/message/13458#13458

For convenience, here the content copied from the link:

Locks are handled in the context of a transaction - not of commands.

Therefore, even if you have autocommit set to on (which is a session-level setting) then the procedure call gets executed (including all other procedures that get called in-between) and only afterwards the transaction is finished (either via ROLLBACK or COMMIT)

With that all locks are released.

So, yes, the rows that get locked in the "inner" calls will still be locked in the "outer" call.

However, since this is all one single transaction, the "outer" call can of course access the records locked by the "inner" call.

Comment: I can't seem to find the documentation for `FOR UPDATE` in the *SQLScript reference*. Where is it documented if not there?

Comment: Thanks. But does *HANA* claim that *SQLScript* is a strict superset of *SQL*? And which *SQL* — `SQL-92`? I did not a statement to that effect in *SQLScript Reference* ...

Comment: So what’s the point here? You don’t find the documentation where you thought it should be? There’s search functions for that both online as well as in HANA studio.

Comment: I now see that it is documented in *SAP HANA SQL and system views reference*. I would have been grateful if you wrote that.

Comment: There are two similarly named documents that contain the words SQL and REFERENCE. One of them you already ruled out and I pointed you to the other one. I cannot help it if that’s still too hard to look up for you, even though both documents are literally on the same web page/built into the tool. Arguing back about SQL standard adherence isn’t help with that either.

Comment: I though you meant *SQL* in general, e.g. the standard `SQL-92`.